# Hadoop 2.2.0 No AbstractFileSystem for scheme: s3n

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3

Environment: Ubuntu, Hadoop 2.2.0, Amazon s3n as filesystem

1. When I submit a job, I get the following error. Checked CLASS_PATH and hadoop configuration in general. All looks good. I am able to list s3 directories ( hdfs dfs -ls /).

14/02/24 20:40:55 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
14/02/24 20:40:55 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hduser (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No AbstractFileSystem for scheme: s3n
14/02/24 20:40:55 INFO mapreduce.Cluster: Failed to use org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnClientProtocolProvider due to error: Error in instantiating YarnClient
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.initialize(Cluster.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.(Cluster.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.(Cluster.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.init(JobClient.java:470)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.(JobClient.java:449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamJob.submitAndMonitorJob(StreamJob.java:1011)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamJob.run(StreamJob.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.HadoopStreaming.main(HadoopStreaming.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)

1. When I change core-site.xml and use local file system ( started dfs as well) then everything works as expected.

Need help in resolving the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps this is stale, but take a  look at the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/26491972/541202