# YARN log aggregation on AWS EMR - UnsupportedFileSystemException

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, emr, amazon-emr, hadoop2

I am struggling to enable YARN log aggregation for my Amazon EMR cluster.  I am following this documentation for the configuration:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-debugging.html#emr-plan-debugging-logs-archive

Under the section titled: "To aggregate logs in Amazon S3 using the AWS CLI".

I've verified that the hadoop-config bootstrap action puts the following in `yarn-site.xml`

```
<property><name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name><value>true</value></property>
<property><name>yarn.log-aggregation.retain-seconds</name><value>-1</value></property>
<property><name>yarn.log-aggregation.retain-check-interval-seconds</name><value>3000</value></property>
<property><name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir</name><value>s3://mybucket/logs</value></property>
```

I can run a sample job (`pi` from `hadoop-examples.jar`) and see that it completed successfully on the ResourceManager's GUI.

It even creates a folder under `s3://mybucket/logs` named with the application id.  But the folder is empty, and if I run `yarn logs -applicationID <applicationId>`, I get a stacktrace:

```
14/10/20 23:02:15 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /10.XXX.XXX.XXX:9022
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No AbstractFileSystem for scheme: s3
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.createFileSystem(AbstractFileSystem.java:154)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.get(AbstractFileSystem.java:242)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$2.run(FileContext.java:333)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$2.run(FileContext.java:330)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getAbstractFileSystem(FileContext.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFSofPath(FileContext.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSLinkResolver.resolve(FSLinkResolver.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.listStatus(FileContext.java:1388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.logaggregation.LogCLIHelpers.dumpAllContainersLogs(LogCLIHelpers.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.cli.LogsCLI.run(LogsCLI.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.cli.LogsCLI.main(LogsCLI.java:199)
```

Which is doesn't make any sense to me; I can run `hdfs dfs -ls s3://mybucket/` and it lists the contents just fine.  The machines are getting credentials from AWS IAM Roles, I've tried adding fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId and such to `core-site.xml` with no change in behavior.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: It appears that there is a difference between the `AbstractFileSystem` interface and the `FileSystem` interface. The usual config options _i.e._ `fs.s3.impl` and `fs.s3n.impl` configure implementations of the `FileSystem` interface, but for some reason yarn is looking for implementations of the `AbstractFileSystem` interface, which can be configured using `fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3.impl`.

Comment: See https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml and look for "AbstractFileSystem".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hadoop provides two fs interfaces - [FileSystem](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/index.html?org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) and [AbstractFileSystem](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/AbstractFileSystem.html). Most of the time, we work with `FileSystem` and use configuration options like `fs.s3.impl` to provide custom adapters.

`yarn logs`, however, uses the `AbstractFileSystem` interface.

If you can find an implementation of that for S3, you can specify it using `fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3.impl`.

See [core-default.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml) for examples of `fs.AbstractFileSystem.hdfs.impl` etc.